# What is this argument of AGGREGATE function doing in my formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I need to understand this part `($B$1:$B$15<>"")` in the following formula used to represent a column of data with blank cells removed:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$15,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($B$1:$B$15)-ROW($B$1)+1)/($B$1:$B$15<>""),ROWS(C$1:C1))),"")
```

This formula was given on another site for the question [Remove Blanks from a Column with Formula](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/603118-remove-blanks-column-formula.html), but I could not find more info about it.
I especially want to know what this part does: `($B$1:$B$15<>"")`.
I can guess it is a range not `""`, but I cannot figure it out its usage in that formula.

Can someone help me on this matter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you queried is doing as you say:

`$B$1:$B$15<>""`

That returns an array of `TRUE/FALSE` values, `FALSE` if each cell is blank and `TRUE` if it's not. In the formula an array of the relative row numbers is divided by that array - when you divide by `TRUE` that acts as a 1 so you just get the row number, when you divide by FALSE that acts like zero so you get a `#DIV/0!` error.

`AGGREGATE` function is set to ignore errors so it finds the `kth` smallest row where `B1:B15` is not blank

......then `INDEX` returns the actual value for that cell.

In cell one - C1 ideally - k = 1 so you get the first non-blank value then ROWS function increments as you copy down so you get each subsequent non-blank value

Comment: Thank you very much Barry, This explanation is pretty clear to me and now I can figure it out.